# hold the value from form through keyup

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an input field through which i am getting the value that user enters, although i am able to display it but instead of displaying it, i wish to store the user entry in a variable and then use it to get data from database. Below is the code that i have so far ([@JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/learner001/hdob6cb1/))

```
<form action="save.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" value="" id="test">
    <p></p>
    <input type="text" value="">
    <button type="button">submit</button>
</form>

    <script>
    $( "input" )
      .keyup(function() {
        var value = $( this ).val();
        $( "p" ).text( value );
      })
      .keyup();
    </script>
```

E.g: if a user enters 12 in input box and then click enter button, then 12 should get stored in a variable, but the whole form should not get submitted after every value of input field is filled then only the form should get submitted

```
$idd=12;
```

and then i wish to run a query as

```
$sql=" SELECT * from menu where id = '".$idd."' ";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            /*
             *
             * code to display data
             *
             */
        }
}
```

and the result that i need to display will come from the code running inside while loop 
Can anyone please tell how to obtain the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this code, you store the result to a variable declared before the `keyup` event.

```
<input type="text" value="some text">
<p></p>

<script>
var inputValue;
$( "input" )
  .keyup(function() {
    inputValue = $(this).val();
  })
  .keyup();
</script>
```

Than you could do your AJAX call.

**EDIT**

Here's the code that only respond to the "enter" keycode

```
var value;
$('input').on('keyup', function(ev) {
  if(ev.keyCode == 13) {
    value = $(this).val();
  }
});
```

Comment: it is storing each letter the word i enter, but i wish to save the whole word only once at the end

Comment: I changed the answer to have that behavior

Comment: your code is working fine, if i have one input in the page but is conflicting with my submit button, i have also updated my post for better understanding, would appreciate if u could go thru it once more

Comment: You need to add something like an id attribute to your input in the HTML and replace the `'input'` by the selector with the id.
Also you should make the answer as valid for people that will have the same question as you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ajax to post value of input box  and get the result like this

```
   <form action="save.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" value="" id="test">
    <p></p>
    <input type="text" value="">
    <button type="button" id="btnsubmit">submit</button>
</form>

<script>
    var value
    $("input").keyup(function () {
                value = $(this).val();
            })
            $('#btnSubmit').click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "url_of_php_page",
                    data: {id: value},
                    success: function (html)
                    {
                        $("p").text(html);
                    }
                });
           });



</script>
```

Comment: is taking each letter of the word, but i need single word at end, can u plz go thru the post again i have updated it

Answer (score 0):

You can do by two ways

```
  <input type="text" value="some text" id="input_id" name="input_name">
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
```

With jquery/ajax

```
  $('#input_id').on('keyup', function() {
  var field_value = $("#input_id").val();
    jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'post', 
    url: 'path_to_the_file',
    data: { fieldValue: field_value },
    success: function(successData) {
        //do whatever want on success
    }
   });
 });
```

Or without jquery/ajax On same page

```
  if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
    $my_value = $_POST['input_name'];
   //Execute your query
  }
```

Comment: you code is adding each letter or word but i need whole work only once at the end, and i also have updated the post can u plz go thru it once more